# Infinite Recursion using callback function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Experimenting with jQuery and trying to make a small slide show that rotates through three images.  Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="slideShow">
    <img src="images/slides/slide1.jpg" width="520" height="230" />
    <img src="images/slides/slide2.jpg" width="520" height="230" />
    <img src="images/slides/slide3.jpg" width="520" height="230" />       
 </div>
```

And here's the script:

```
$(function ()
{
    var $slides = $('#slideShow img').hide(),
    slideIndex = 0;

    slideTransition = function ()
    {
        slideIndex++;
        (slideIndex == $slides.length) ? slideIndex = 0: null;
        $slides.eq(slideIndex).fadeIn(3000);
        $slides.eq(slideIndex).fadeOut(3000,slideTransition);
    }

    $slides.eq(0).fadeIn(3000);
    $slides.eq(0).fadeOut(3000, slideTransition);

});
```

This actually works fine, but my gut is telling me that having the infinite recursion is a bad thing.  Any suggestions on how to do this better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're doing is not recursion.  When the animation starts, your call returns.  Then, a timer event handler invokes your method.  Your solution is just fine.

Comment: Ah, so the statement is executed, but the callback isn't called until the animation is complete?

Answer (score 0):

To remove infinite recursion and running gallery you can use jquery' "animate" function. The reference is here http://api.jquery.com/animate/.